# Python - convert string to simple YYYY date format

Tags: python

New to Python, and have already spent 30 minutes reviewing old responses, but still can't figure this out.

'Year' variable is a string. Examples: 1990, 2010.
I need to convert to date format, but just with the 4 year "digits".
Tried the following, but none are working:

```
date1 = datetime.datetime.date('Year', "%Y")
datetime.datetime.strftime('Year', "%Y")
wcData.astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime('Year', format='%Y'))
df.astype(str).apply(lambda x: pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y%m%d'))
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You need [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime), not `strftime`:

```
import datetime

datetime.datetime.strptime("2010", "%Y")
```

Here's how to remember which one to use:

- `strPtime` means "`str`ing -> `p`arse -> `time`", that is, *parse* a string to create some kind of object that represents time;
- `strFtime` means "`str`ing <- `f`ormat <- `time`" (note the reversed arrows), that is, given an object that represents time, create a string representation of it using some format.

Comment: AttributeError: type object 'datetime.datetime' has no attribute 'datetime'.    Received this error.

Comment: @shanev13, yeah, that the module has a class with the same name is pretty confusing. I've updated my answer.